# How to check query statement in Linq to NHibernate?

Tags: .net, linq-to-nhibernate

I'd like to see sql query once linq to nhibernate query is executed to log or check sql query.
How can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could either [configure log4net](http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/configure-log4net-for-use-with-nhibernate.aspx) or use an SQL Profiler to see what's actually sent to the database. Yet another option (if you are willing to spend a few bucks) is to checkout Ayende's excellent [tool](http://nhprof.com/).

Comment: In order to log query in NHibernate using log4Net, Which API do I need to use in NHibernate, actually this is really what I want to know.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SQL Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa173918(SQL.80).aspx).